# What happens when I use javaw to run the java program in the following scenario?

Tags: java, io, javaw, console-input

Say suppose I am running a java program through command line. And this program requires some data to enter during the execution. So I was wondering on what happens if somebody uses javaw to run this type of program?

That is how to enter the data to the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get interactive input, but if you wanted to read from a file, you could, or you could redirect standard input to a file or pipe.

```
cat myText.txt | javaw myJavaClass
```

or Windows

```
type myText.txt | javaw myjavaClass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Since `javaw` doesn't allocate a console you have no way of entering data.

Comment: Could you not redirect standard in to a file, or similar?

Comment: @Stefan: You simply won't have the stdin, stdout and stderr streams. Those only exist for console applications. So no, redirection very likely won't work.